# XML being returned in String form needs to be Converted into a java bean

Tags: java, xml, string

I have written a java web service client program, which calls a method that takes country name as input parameter and returns City names as String which is in XML format.

Sample XML returned and stored in a String variable is as follows..

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country>
    <City>Diego Garcia</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Ahmadabad</City>
  </Table>
  ......
</NewDataSet>
```

Can anyone please help me on how i can convert this xml which is stored in a `String` variable is converted into a Cities.java bean which has two accessers for `Country` and `City`.

Thank you,
Prathap.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) for this task, it's a Java standard for converting XML files into objects.

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Cities.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Cities response = (Cities) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

You also need to annotate your Cities class like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Cities {

    @XmlElement
    private String coutry;

    @XmlElement
    private String city;

    //setters and getters

}
```

This should work for you. You can also use `@XmlElement(name="")` to customize binding of XML elements to Java properties.

Comment: If your members are private you'd also need public getter and setter methods for JAXB to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAXB to create an object representation of your XML file. Here the "NewDataSet" element contains a list of child (Table) elements. With JAXB, you can create an instance of "NewDataSet" which will in turn contain a list of "Table" objects. And then you can iterate through the list to get the values of "Country" and "City" of each "Table". Here is how you can do this:

This will represent the "Table" element of your XML.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Table {
private String country;
private String city;

// getters and setters
}
```

and this is your "NewDataSet" which contains a list of "Table" elements:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class NewDataSet {
private List<Table> tableList;

public List<Table> getTableList() {
    return tableList;
}

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "NewDataSet")
    @XmlElement(name = "Table")
    public void setCustomerList(List<Table> tableList) {
        this.tableList =tableList;
    }
}
```

Now using JAXB unmarshaller you can create an instance of "NewDataSet":

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(NewDataSet.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader("your xml as string");
NewDataSet newDataSet = (NewDataSet) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Ref: [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLBeans library to parse the XML.

http://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/tutorial_getstarted.html